# Codeigniter doesn't save sessions in database

Tags: codeigniter, session

In config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cookiename';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
//$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
//$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` BLOB NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

That doesn't save the session in the database and the API doesn't return any response. If I change it to files it works fine.

[update]

Now I get this error:

```
Exception: Configured database connection is persistent. Aborting. /var/app/current/system/
libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php 94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take in consideration your dbprefix config.

If it's `'isci_'`, then your sessions table should be named `'isci_sessions'` and `sess_save_path` the same.

Also you should change your database pconnect config to FALSE to fix the last issue.

Comment: db has no prefix it's name is something like 'mydb' just like that and table name is 'ci_sessions'

Comment: I meant db table prefix. It's in your database config.

Comment: 'dbprefix' => '',

Comment: Exception: Configured database connection is persistent. Aborting. /var/app/current/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php 94

Comment: You can change your database config, pconnect to FALSE.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help the last change solved the issue